# Novel with a city in slowed time

Tags: story-identification, time-dilation

A video showing laminar flow reminded me of a novel I read in my childhood, but I don't remember much of it, including the title or author.

What I *do* remember, however, is that there was a room with a "mirror", and said mirror actually turned out to be a window/portal into a region containing a city suspended in extremely slowed time - the protagonist returns several times to *minor* changes in the scenery, and he *may* have interacted with the slowed-time city to alter events, like a shootout, exploiting the difference in speed his "normal-time" status means in the slowed-time city. There is also a ambush that takes place just as the protagonist exits the slowed-time region, with some inner monologue telling that he [the protagonist *or* his assailant] did not know/remember that the vertical axis changes at the interface.
There is also a lingering image in my mind that the entire novel actually takes place on a gigantic spaceship, which is transporting the city to another system, and they used the time dilation technology to allow surreptitious transport while also reducing resource requirements.

I don't know when the novel was authored, but I probably read it in the early nineties, most likely translated to Hungarian.

To put things in a bullet point list:

- I'm looking for a novel, read early nineties, possibly written in the eighties
- I read it in Hungarian, but that was likely not the original language
- Involves a city suspended in slowed time
- Protagonist visits multiple times, sometimes using his "normal-time" status to make changes to events
- Access to slowed-time city is through a silvery surface that is initially mistaken as a mirror
- There is a fight where a key detail is that the vertical axis/axis of gravity changes at the interface surface
- The city is likely being transported to another star system in slowed time aboard a spaceship

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Put things in a bullet list so it's easier to analyze.